# Linux Operating system recovery after abnormal termination

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

How does the operating system (Linux) while rebooting checks whether abnormal termination happened during last shutdown and then does the file system consistent checks etc if required ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filesystems write a mark before mounting a volume read-write and reset this mark after successfully closing all write operations and unmounting (or mounting read-only). See https://ext4.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Ext4_Disk_Layout#The_Super_Block

Comment: what other checks are performed while the system reboots after abnormal termination ?

Comment: @Sanket File system check is about it. If you need to check something else (application-level data consistency) you have to explicitly put it into the start-up scripts.

Comment: Similar to the journal run of a FS is (or may be in a good configuration) the sync run of a RAID. That is even before the FS is seen, of course. In contrast to a file system check or journal run the RAID sync doe not block the system, though (unless you prefer it) because this can be done in the background.